# Passing Image to another View Controller (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, uibutton

I'm trying to move a user uploaded image from one *UIImageView* to another *UIImageView* on a different View Controller. I'm able to have the user upload an image and have it saved in the first *UIImageView* but after they press the "Post" button, the UIImageView on the next view controller remains blank.

Note: browsingImage is the name of the UIImageView on the second view controller (destination UIImageView)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
@IBAction func cameraButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    addNewPicture()

}


func addNewPicture() {

    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.allowsEditing = true
    picker.delegate = self

    presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {

    postingImage.image = image
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}

@IBAction func postButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    performSegueWithIdentifier("toBrowsePage", sender: nil)


}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "toBrowsePage" {


        var itemToAdd = segue.destinationViewController as! ListPage

        itemToAdd.postingImage.image = browsingImage.image

    }

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be itemToAdd.browsingImage.image = postingImage.image ?

Answer (score 25):

In `prepare(for:)` you can't access the `@IBOutlet`s of the destination view controller because they haven't been set up yet.  You should assign the image to a property of the destination view controller, and then move it into place in `viewDidLoad()`:

In source view controller:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toBrowsePage" {
        let dvc = segue.destination as! ListPage
        dvc.newImage = postingImage.image
    }
}
```

In destination view controller:

```
class ListPage: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var browsingImage: UIImageView!
    var newImage: UIImage!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        browsingImage.image = newImage
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your description,`browsingImage` is in destination viewController,so 
in this line

```
itemToAdd.postingImage.image = browsingImage.image
```

You pass the destination imageview to source imageview

Answer (score 1):

IBOutlets are not accessible in your current view controller. The outlets are not yet initialized since the **your second view is not yet loaded**.

Instead you can create a UIImage variable in your second viewController and assign the value to it in the prepareForSegue.

And in your second viewController's viewDidLoad method assign that value to your ImageView outlet.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "toBrowsePage" {
        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! ListPage
        destination.receivedImage = postingImage.image
    }
}
```

In your next viewController declare a variable called

```
@IBOutlet weak var postingImage: UIImageView!
var receivedImage : UIImage?
```

In the viewDidLoad method

```
postingImage.image = receivedImage
```

Answer (score 0):

At the time of the `Segue` happening your UIImageView is not initialised so you can not assign an image to it, the best practise would be to pass the `UIImage` and initialise your `UIImageView` in `viewDidLoad`.

so in your `ListPage` class make a property of type `UIImage` change your `prepareForSegue` line as

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "toBrowsePage" {


        var itemToAdd = segue.destinationViewController as! ListPage

        itemToAdd.image = browsingImage.image

        }

    }
```

in `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear` of your destination `viewController` you will do something like this

```
browsingImage.image = image
```