# Accessing image from prepare segue error

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

1. Normally, we link the image from storyboard to viewcontroller by `IBOutlet` by this code:

   ```
   @IBOutlet private weak var resultImage: UIImageView!
   ```

we can update the image by calling this: `resultImage.image = UIImage(named: "image")`. It works ok

2. However, when i call this in the prepare for segue, it found nil:

   ```
   let destinationDetail = segue.destination as! RestaurantViewController       
   destinationDetail.restaurantImage.image = UIImage(named: "image")
   ```

restaurantImage is an Outlet in RestaurantViewController: @IBOutlet weak var restaurantImage: UIImageView!

I dont understand why it found nil, please help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31576232/passing-image-to-another-view-controller-swift

Answer (score 0):

Because view controlle haven't been set up yet. you can use IBOutlet after view is load. 
In viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear of your destination viewController you will do something like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    resultImage.image = newImage
}
```