# Swift 3 - Unable to pass image from one viewcontroller to second

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

i am trying to pass an image from 1st `UIViewController` to 2nd `UIViewControlleler` by prepareforSegue

my code :-

```
extension ViewController:UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {
func handleImg() {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.allowsEditing = true
    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    var selectedImageFromPicer : UIImage?
    if let editedImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"] as? UIImage {
        selectedImageFromPicer = editedImage
    } else if let originalImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {

        selectedImageFromPicer = originalImage
    }

    if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicer {
        imgg.image = selectedImage  
    }
    guard let imageUrl = info["UIImagePickerControllerImageURL"] as? URL else {
        return
    }
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "selected", sender: self)
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        print("canceled picker")
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "selected" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! secondVC
        vc.img.image = self.imgg.image

    }
}
```

i am getting the error on line `vc.img.image = self.imgg.image`

Error

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31576232/passing-image-to-another-view-controller-swift, and verify data in not nil.You can use if-let to handle nil values.

Comment: Check is your segue in storyboard named "selected" and the type of destination view controller (by your code it's "secondVC"). It could be because vc is nil.

Comment: try vc.img= self.imgg instead

Comment: @Eridana yess i have checked segue named and second vc's name

Comment: @YinKiet doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that error because of self.imgg.image is nil. So you are only setting imgg when it is not empty like this:

```
if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicer {
    imgg.image = selectedImage  
}
```

but what if this code is never run, then it will throw an error that unexpectedly found nil.

So when you are setting it for second VC, first check if it is not null and then set it like this:

```
vc.img.image = self.imgg.image
```

Comment: cannot understand

Comment: Just do a nil check before you assign it to your secondvc in this line `vc.img.image = self.imgg.image'

Answer (score 0):

Create variable in secondVC of type UIImage and from your first viewcontroller set image in that variable

You are getting this exception because views of secondVC is not yet created in memory.

So in FirstVC apply following changes

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "selected" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! secondVC
        vc.image = self.imgg.image

    }
}
```

In secondVC apply following changes

Declare `var image: UIImage? = nil`

And in viewDidLoad() set image to imageView

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.img.image = image
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: Are you getting same exception after implementing this?

Comment: image does not showing on second vc

Comment: Can you upload your code somewhere so that code can be debug?

Comment: i can send u code

Comment: Please upload your code on Github or Dropbox and send link