# UIImage and prepareforSegue not able to pass the image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

Here my code :

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *chosedImage;

    - (IBAction)cropImageTap:(id)sender {

        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
             UIImage * pickedImage = self->_chosedImage;
            //[UIImage imageNamed:@"helloWorld.jpg"];

            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"gotomainimage" sender:pickedImage];

        }];
    }
```

And my perform segue is below :

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {


        PostVC *vc = (PostVC*)segue.destinationViewController;
        UIImage *img = (UIImage*)sender;

        if (img.images == nil) {
            NSLog(@"null img");
             vc.Sourcemage = img;
        }
        else {

             NSLog(@"not null img");
             vc.Sourcemage = img;
        }

    }
```

I am getting null image only.My image is not coming.What the issue i am doing here ?

Please help me out

UPDATED :

My updated code, work like - giving me console message like :

its null dataa - post vc
 its not an null image - prepareForSegue method

Not able to find out why ist happening.

```
     - (IBAction)cropImageTap:(id)sender {


        UIImageView * pickedImage = _chosedImage;
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"gotomainimage" sender:pickedImage.image];
        }];
    }

    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {

        PostVC *vc = (PostVC*)segue.destinationViewController;
        UIImage *img = (UIImage*)sender;

        if (img != nil) {
             NSLog(@"its not an null image");
            vc.Sourcemage = img;

        } else {
             NSLog(@"its an null image");
        }
    }

in my postvc :

    @property(nonatomic) UIImage *Sourcemage;
    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];



        if (self.Sourcemage != nil){
            NSLog(@"not null dataa");

            _PostImageView.image = _Sourcemage;

        } else {
    NSLog(@"not null dataa");
           _PostImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Travel.png"];
        }


    }
```

Comment: I suggest you to use this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31576232/passing-image-to-another-view-controller-swift

Comment: Your view controller, that holds the image, is dismissed in the completion block. Try to put this: UIImage * pickedImage = self->_chosedImage; one line above.

Comment: @Cristian i am getting thsi warning `iincompatible pointer types initializing 'UIImage *' with an expression of type 'UIImageView *'`

Comment: @Cristian  check my updated one...its not shoing the image

Comment: Please show us code of PostVC of Sourcemage variable

Comment: @Arnab Hore i have added.Please check it out

Comment: @chandrukin That warning was because you were passing an UIImageView to an UIImage, but I see that you figured that out. There may be a problem with your _PostImageView, you can check its frame by displaying it in the console, or make sure you don't have other view that covers your _PostImageView, by having it displayed above _PostImageView.

Comment: @chandrukin If you just put this line in your viewWillAppear: _PostImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Travel.png"]; does the image show? (assuming that you have that image in your xcode project) . If it shows, then most likely it's not a problem here, but in your initial controller, from where you are initially passing the image. If it doesn't show, then most likely there is a problem with your _PostImageView, and you will have to check its frame, position and hierarchy.

Comment: yes, on else statement that image is showing if its null

Comment: @chandrukin If you get rid of the [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{ ..... }]; line and just keep performSegueWithIdentifier what do you get? Also seems odd that you are dismissing a controller and performing a segue right after. Try to get rid of this approach, let only the performSegueWithIdentifier and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Is the variable Sourcemage in your destination viewcontroller(PostVC) is UIImage?

Please check whether the property is UIImage or not.

Comment: @property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage* Sourcemage; its in my postvc.h

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are passing **`UIImageView`** instead of **`UIImage`**

Update your code as below,

```
UIImageView * pickedImage = _chosedImage;
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"gotomainimage" sender:pickedImage.image];
}];
```

in above code, you must pass **`UIImage`** not **`UIImageView`** itself and handle it like this,

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    PostVC *vc = (PostVC*)segue.destinationViewController;
    UIImage *img = (UIImage*)sender;
    vc.Sourcemage = img;
}
```

Comment: NOW Image is coming but in my postvc ist not showing that is the isses..like here `_PostImageView.image = _Sourcemage;`

Comment: are you getting pickedImage.image?

Comment: what you actually want to do?

Comment: from one vc to another vc i am passing the image to show.That only not shoing

Comment: after updated ur code, `pickedImage` itself getting null value

Comment: Yes that is the thing, it is null, try to pass UIImage object there and you will get succeed

Comment: but i dont want to pass the uiimage view of `_chosedImage`.this only holding the image selction..so only

Comment: try passing _chosedImage.image

Comment: please check my full updated code..ist not happening.please give me some solution..i m hittig more than 1 hr

Comment: Any luck in this issues ??

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do like this?

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    PostVC *vc = (PostVC*)segue.destinationViewController;
    vc.Sourcemage = _checkedImage;
}
```